# Does Ubuntu have any built-in support for mirroring a directory?

Tags: backup

I don't mean anything involving rsync etc, I mean built-in support in the file system, so when I create and write to a file in /home/me/path it also creates and writes a duplicate in /elsewhere/path.

Comment: It has sshfs have you tried that?

Comment: Why would an OS need built-in support for that?  This is so specific for a target the best option would be to create your own script. Python, module watchdog and 2 minutes of your time and you have it running as a personal systemd service.